# The Electric field & Coulomb's law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

A point charge is moving in an electric field at right angles to the lines of forces .Does any force act on it ? Please explain why.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a force is still acting on the particle.

Moving perpendicular to the lines of force may result in no *work* being done ($W = \mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{r}$) , but since the particle is charged, it will be experiencing a force when moving through any electric field.

If the particle is (initially) moving in the $y$ direction and the electric field is in the $x$ direction, so that $x$ and $y$ are perpendicular, then the particle will slowly develop a velocity component in the direction of the field.

Mathematically: Netwton's second law is $m\frac{d^2\mathbf{r}}{dt^2} = \mathbf{F}$; assuming the charge of the particle is $q$, the force acting on it by an electric field $\mathbf{E}$ is $\mathbf{F} = q\mathbf{E} $.

So $m\frac{d^2\mathbf{r}}{dt^2} =  q\mathbf{E}$.

Now let's split this into the $x$ and $y$ directions:

x) $m\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} =  qE_x$,

solution: $x(t) = x_0 + v_{x initial}t +\frac{1}{2}{qE_x \over m}t^2$;

assuming the particle starts from 0 and with no velocity along the direction of the field, $x(t) = \frac{1}{2}{qE_x \over m}t^2$ : it will slowly ($\sim t^2$) acquire a velocity component in the direction of the field)

y) $m\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} =  qE_y = 0$ since the electric field in the x direction.

solution: $y(t) = y_0 + v_{y initial}t$;

No force is acting along $y$, so the $y$ component of the velocity will remain the same as it was before entering the electric field.